# Auth0 on Heroku: Infinite redirect loop on login

Tags: django, heroku, auth0

I am attempting to set up a django app on heroku that uses auth0. Previously I have not had an issue with any of these things and it all worked fine locally. However they seem to have come together to make a perfect storm of an issue.

Upon submitting a login with auth0 using the google oauth, the page redirects back to the login. This is an infinite loop. Previously when it was remembering the user it would do this infinitely. If it is not remembering it will simply take you back to the initial login page at domain.com/login/auth0.

[Here is how the server handles it locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTb76.png), [and here is the loop on heroku.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnyQ6.png)

Everything on the django end is boilerplate, and as mentioned, works fine locally. The auth0 redirects are set up properly, as is the google-oauth setup with auth0. Independently all these things work fine, but for some reason they are breaking down on heroku.

It is worth mentioning that when the user was being remembered and the infinite loop cycled through, eventually it hit an error page that mentioned this may be caused by disabling or refusing cookies. It is also worth noting that the auth0 site even reports the login as a success (bizarrely). I suspect there may be some issue transferring data from the heroku domain to the auth0 one.

Any insight to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please can you share code snippet

Comment: Could you please tell more about your client-side code and architecture please ? Thanks